# How does apple set the Delegates of the UIKit classes as Outlets?

Tags: delegates, uikit, protocols

I've been trying to find a way to set the delegates on my custom classes as Outlets so I can connect them via IB just like one does with an UIKit Class but I haven't been able to do this, is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will need to the `IBOutlet` keyword to the delegate property.

Like:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id <YourDelegateClass>   delegate;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is actually pretty obvious but I guess I ignored this option because I didn't see the IBOutlet declaration in the UIKit classes header files I was checking out. I assume the IBOutlet is set in the implementation file like this for example 
    
    @implementation LLNavigationBarView {
        IBOutlet id<LLNavigationBarViewDelegate> delegate;
    }

Is this assumption right?

Also, can you think of a reason why I want to keep this IBOutlet declaration in the implementation file?

Comment: Yes this could be, or maybe it has to do some rewrites when swift can along. Because I remember it being in their source files.

Comment: So there is actually not a good reason to keep this IBOutlet in the implementation file right?

Comment: No not really, I've never done it. I only expose what needs to be exposed. Never more then that.